# Configure AppContextSwitchOverrides in ASP.NET Core 3.1 or 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I configure AppContextSwitchOverrides in ASP.NET Core projects?

I tried adding the setting in web.config but it does not seems to take effect. Like so:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="AppContext.SetSwitch:Switch.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.LegacyRowVersionNullBehavior" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're adding that switch to correct the EF Core null value exception when using the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 3.0.0? If so, you might want to read this thread about the problem. The switch does not eliminate the error in the case where EF Core retrieves a null related object containing a timestamp property. EF Core needs fixing, and it isn't apparently happening yet.
[GitHub problem report](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25074)

Comment: Yeah.., apparently it is not setting issue. There's a bug in the way EF Core handles null timestamp...